# Jquery how do you get the string from an Id in your html and compare it to another string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when user clicks the letter, it changes the weathertype and converts temperature.
For example when i click #weatherType, i want it to change to fahrenheit
and when I want to go back to celcius, i will just click the #weatherType again
But when I click it, it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: here is my codepen https://codepen.io/angelbenoit/pen/RjJPyK

```
 $('#weatherType').click(function () {
                var check = $('#weatherType').text();
                if(check === "C"){
                    $('#weatherType').html("F");
                    $('#convertTemperature').html(fahrenheit);
                }
                else{
                    $('#weatherType').html("C");
                    $('#convertTemperature').html(celcius);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve] please

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? are `fahrenheit` and `celcius` functions or variables that return or contain HTML code with the previously processed calculation?

Comment: Any errors in console? Does `$('#weatherType')` exist when you run this code? That is just two unknowns for us without seeing enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: Remove var declarations for celcius and fahrenheit (you didn't set values, vars/values are set in another part of code/function), and it will work: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjJPqV

Comment: Awesome thanks sinisake, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this.

```
<button id='weatherType'>C</button>
<div id='convertTemperature'>celcius</div>
```

And

```
$("#weatherType").click(function() {
  var check = $(this).text();
  if (check === "C") {
    $(this).text("F");
    $("#convertTemperature").text("fahrenheit");
  } else {
    $(this).text("C");
    $("#convertTemperature").text("celcius");
  }
});
```

**See live preview:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/BmVNqJ

For Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius:

```
 $("#weatherType").click(function() {
      var check = $(this).text();
      if (tempUnit === check) {
        $(this).text("F");            
        $("#convertTemperature").text(fahrenheit);
      } else {
        $(this).text("C");       
        $("#convertTemperature").text(celcius);
      }
  });
```

**Here is the preview:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/JOZYJW

Answer (score -1):

You need to rebind click event on click

```
$('#weatherType').click(function () {
  performConversion();
  });

function performConversion(){
var check = $('#weatherType').text();
                if(check === "C"){
                    $('#weatherType').html("F");
                    $('#convertTemperature').html(fahrenheit);
                }
                else{
                    $('#weatherType').html("C");
                    $('#convertTemperature').html(celcius);
                }
$('#weatherType').unbind("click");
$('#weatherType').click(function () {
  performConversion();
  })

}
```

Comment: Why would he need to do that?

Comment: Because you are replacing HTML in you div so you need to again bind click event for that div

Comment: Without a [mcve] we can't clearly see anything. BTW I wasn't the one who downvoted you